# Use Regex to get statement from URL

Tags: python, html, url

So I have this IMDB link where i want to extract the genre only so I'm already using this code

```
# genre
genre = movie.find('span',class_="genre")
if genre != None:
    genre = str(genre).split(', <p class="genre">')[0].replace("\n", "").replace("</p>]", "")
    
else:
    genre = "Not Found"
IMDB_dict[title].append(genre)
```

To give me output as

```
<span class="genre">Drama,Fantasy,Horror </span>
```

as seen in picture:

[image: here]

But I want to only output Drama, Fantasy, Horror and not the that stuff above.
May I please know how to do this as I have put some Regex code there to find it but it still returns some kind of URL as seen above.
Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

if you're using BeautifulSoup you can use this

```
genre_text = BeautifulSoup(genre).text
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is the way to go, try to avoid regexes in parsing HTML whenever possible.

Comment: i used it but it gave error so i did this ```genre = SOUP(genre.text, 'lxml')```..and it outputs ```<html><body><p>Horror, Fanatasy, Drama</p>./body></html>```...i think somehow i have to remove this now

Comment: Yeah, I would fiddle around with soup.  OR if you get it really close, soup it, then regex it.

Comment: Yeah right now im trying to do it..but same thing..maybe im missing something

Answer (score 0):

This regex will extract any content between any string containing a *single* open and closed HTML tag with the capture group `(.*)`.

```
^<.*>(.*)<\/.*>$
```

Python:

```py
import re

genre = '<span class="genre">Drama,Fantasy,Horror </span>'

regx = r'^<.*>(.*)<\/.*>$'
text = re.findall(regx, genre)
print(text)
```

Output:

```py
['Drama,Fantasy,Horror ']
```

Comment: `re.compile` returns compiled pattern. Either drop this line or assign to some variable and use `findall` as it's method (`regex = re.compile(...); result = regex.findall(...)`). Also please don't use `match` as variable name, although it is still allowed (pattern matching made it a soft keyword). Also raw strings (with `r` prefix) are more suitable for regexes.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, haven't been doing regex in Python recently. Thanks @SUTerliakov